# Calculating the time for a person to do a work, given their probability to get it done

Tags: probability, ratio

$X = x_1, x_2, x_3$
$Y = y_1, y_2, y_3$
...

For any person $X$ in this list:

- $x_1$ is the time he takes to do the work,
- $ \dfrac{x_2}{x_3}$ is the probability he gets the work done.

Consider this example, only $2$ persons:
$X = 2, 1, 4$ and $Y = 5, 2, 3$

- $X$ *takes $2$ hrs and $\dfrac{1}{4}$ chances he does the work*
- $Y$ *takes $5$ hrs and $\dfrac{2}{3}$ chances he does the work*

If I choose $X$,
- $X$ does the work, time taken = $2$
- $X$ does not do the work, time taken = $2 + 5$
I will have to resort to $Y$ to do the work after having wasted time with $X$, hence $Y$'s time has to be added.

Total time taken = $2\times\dfrac{1}{4} + (2+5)\times\dfrac{3}{4}$

Similarly, if I choose $Y$ first,

Total time taken = $5\times\dfrac{2}{3} + (2+5)\times\dfrac{1}{3}$

If there were more persons to choose from, I will have to add their time too.
So choosing $Y$ from $X, Y, Z$

Total time taken = $5\times\dfrac{2}{3} + (2+5+Z$'s time$)\times\dfrac{1}{3}$

**How can I generalize a formula for calculating the total time taken, if I choose a person**?

I came up with this:
Time taken if I choose a person $X$ from a list of $P$ persons to do the work:

$x_1 \times \dfrac{x_2}{x_3}\ + T\times\dfrac{x_3-x_2}{x_3}$

where,
- T is sum of individual time of all persons, a constant,
- $x_2 < x_3$, $x_1 > 0$
- All numbers are positive integers.

Is this correct?
For what values of $x_1, x_2, x_3$ **can it fail**?

Comment: Before trying to generalize anything, referring to your 2-people example, do you mean you can always force the 2nd person to do the work with probability 1? Or the 2nd person may still refuse to work and you need to pass back to the 1st person (or left that work)?

Comment: What would be the difference in both cases ad how would that impact the solution? I think that's what I am missing

Comment: It is somehow like a markov chain problem - say when person $X$ does not work, and you pass to $Y$, if $Y$ does not work again, your expected working time is not only adding 5. You need to clarify this again. In your example you assume that the 2nd person will always do the work for you.

Comment: @BGM, if the person X does not do the work, I will resort to Y, if he doesn't do it, I will contact Z. So if I choose X first, and go on with worst probability (no body does the work), the last person will definitely do it - take that for granted. To get the work done therefore, the max. possible time if I choose X first, would be obtained by adding the time they take, multiplied by their probabilities + (1 - probability) x everyone else's time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose there is a total of $n$ people, and you have already specify the working order from person $1, 2, \ldots$, up to $n$. Let

- $p_i$ be the probability of the $i$-th person will work, with $p_n = 1$ as required,
- $t_i$ be the constant working time of the $i$-th person, $i = 1, 2, \ldots, n$.

Assuming each person decision is independent, then the probability that the work is finally done by the $i$-th person is
$$ \left[\prod_{j=1}^{i-1}(1 - p_j)\right]p_i, i = 2, 3, \ldots, n$$
The total working time if the work is finally done by the $i$-th person is
$$ \sum_{j=1}^i t_j$$

As a result, the expected total working time is given by
$$ p_1t_1 + \sum_{i=2}^n \left[\prod_{j=1}^{i-1}(1 - p_j)\right]p_i\sum_{j=1}^i t_j$$